# Skip the first element in Python iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

I have a large amount of data returned from a SQL query, then broken up into groups using itertools.groupby()

I need to skip over the first element of each group, then process the rest of them. Will calling next() on the group do this? I'm not very familiar with iterators being used this way.

```
for group in itertools.groupby(...):
    group.next()
    for val in group...
```

Comment: Yes.  That should work.  `for val in group` is really just calling `group.next()` until it gets `StopIteration` anyway.

Comment: Note that `.next()` doesn't exist in Python 3; it's been renamed to `.__next__()`.  Either way, you should use the `next()` function instead of the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The theory is sound, but your code as written won't work because (a) `groupby` returns an iterable of `(key, iterator_over_group)` pairs, not the groups directly, and (b) the `next` method has been renamed to `__next__` in Python 3 (and you should be using the [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) function anyway).  The correct way to write your code is:

```
for key, group in itertools.groupby(...):
    next(group)
    for val in group:
        ...
```